# create a text channel on message react(limit to specific message or specific channel)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

(node:19040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined
at Client. (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Commendbot\app.js:90:30)

```
bot.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user, message) => { //Add an event listener
if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
const channels = message.guild.channels.cache
channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'createchannel')

if (user.id === client.user.id) return; //If the reaction was from the bot, return
if (!reaction.message.guild) return; //If the reaction was not in a guild

if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
  let guild = reaction.message.guild
  guild.channels.create(`channel-${user.id}`, { //Creating the channel
      type: 'text', //Make sure the channel is type is text
      permissionOverwrites: [ //Set overwrites
          {
              id: guild.id,
              allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          }]
      })
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

[`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) only gives 2 objects: the [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) and [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). You can get the message from the reaction

```js
const channels = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache
```